# Magento 2 install stuck at 73%

Tags: magento2

**SOLVED** (see my answer below)

Magento 2 installation with sample data gets stuck at 73%. The last thing it installs is:

```
Module 'Magento_WidgetSampleData':
Installing data...
```

I have set `max_execution_time = 1800` and `memory_limit = 2G` in php.ini.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that the progress stuck at some point but the installation completes. Just check with your DB if the last table is `wishlist_item_option`, installation is complete. Or you can open your URL in new tab.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya there is a `wishlist_item_option` table, but when I go to my site it shows only html content with images without any styling. This is like 5th time I try to install it, but it just stops at 73%.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have nginx not apache. Also I already have a Magento 2 installation that works completely fine. This one that gets stuck at 73% is different version and comes with sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess installation was complete, but just showed that it was stuck like @JaiminSutariya said. I just had to go to the website and run `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, because it only showed html content without any styling.